# Recombining phase and magnitude of sin wave?

Tags: numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have been working on the decorrelation of audio signals. I am following a research paper in which the technique is to generate a sequence number in such a way that magnitude is constant while the phase is varying randomly. 
Now, the issue is I generated a sin wave and I took fft of it, calculated phase and magnitude using NumPy as shown in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, rfft, ifft, irfft

Farendsig = ((np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(48000 * 0.02133) * 2000 / 48000)) * 32767).astype(np.int16)

freq = fft(Farendsig, 1024)  # fft output complex

phase = np.angle(freq)  # phase

magnitude = np.abs(freq)  # magnitude

combined = np.multiply(magnitude, np.exp(1j * phase))

FarendSyth = (ifft(combined, 1024) * (32767 + 0j)).astype(np.int16)
```

Now, when I resynthesized the same signal by following StackOverflow answer : [How to combine the phase of one image and magnitude of the different image into 1 image by using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312053/how-to-combine-the-phase-of-one-image-and-magnitude-of-different-image-into-1-im/52337407)
. The resultant signal is different from the original signal on some indexes. 
What's wrong am I doing here?

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer :

```
FarendSyth = (ifft(combined, 1024)).astype(np.int1
```

I was multiplying ifft result with `32767` and that was causing the issue in the result. Replacing this line in the above code gave exact results.

Thanks